# Extract Last 2 line breaks from excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to achieve the below:

[image]

I would like cell AD3 to pull in the last 2 lines of text from cell AC3, which will be variable and often changing. The text in cell AC3 is all separated by line breaks.

In case you're wondering, currently I just have the values typed into cell AD3 for demonstration of my goal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this down. For ease of writing, I use A1.

You first want to know how many rows are in the cell.

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))
```

This formula returns a count of the character 10, which is the character used for a line break in a cell. If the cell has 5 rows, there will be 4 line break characters. If you want to return the last 2 rows, you want everything after the one but last line break character. To identify the one but last line break, subtract 1.

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))-1
```

Replace the one but last line break character with a character that you know will otherwise not be in your cell, for example the character with code 160, which is a non-printable blank.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(160),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))-1)
```

Next, you want to find the position of the character 160

```
=FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(160),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))-1))
```

Now that you know the position of that character, you can use MID() to return the text after that character (add 1 to the position of that character). Assume that the last two rows of text in A1 are never more than 99 characters, use that for how many characters you want to return. Or use your favourite big number that will do that.

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(160),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))-1))+1,99)
```

[image]

Remember to format the cell with the formula to wrap!

Comment: This worked well! I had o change the formula to the following:

 =MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(160),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))-2))+1,99).

I think this is because maybe there is an extra line break at the end of my cell A1 in your example. Not sure why. Thank you for the detailed response and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this.  Here's one that is easily adaptable to returning other lines.

If you have the functions available in your version of Excel, you can use `FILTERXML` and `TEXTJOIN`

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()>last()-2]"))
```

- `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` creates an XML where the line breaks divide the nodes
- the `xpath` argument `"//s[position()>last()-2]")` returns the last two nodes. Obviously this can be modified an many ways to return other nodes
- `TEXTJOIN` then joins those nodes with a linebreak.

[image]

Comment: While your explanation makes this seem simple, I do not understand how to complete the xpath argument. When I copy and paste your formula and update the cell reference, I am left with "NAME!".

Comment: @BobbyZullo That error usually means you do not have one of the required functions for the formula in your version of Excel, or you have entered the cell reference incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Return the last 2 lines

In `B1`, enter formula :

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",399)),799))
```

[image]

Comment: that removes the line break between the last two lines, no?

Comment: This only gave the first last line of text because I think I have an extra line break at the end of my cell A1 for some reason, and since there was no explanation, I didn't know how to change this formula to fit my needs. Thank you for your response, though!